# if-problem with dot

Tags: php

Following code:

```
<?php
$str = "19.09.02";
if(substr($str, -3, 2) == ".0")
{
    // Doing something
}

$str2 = "19.09.2002";
if(substr($str2, -3, 2) == ".0")
{
    // Doing something
}
?>
```

Why does the second statement apply (without regexp)? and how can I solve, that it just apply the first expression?

Thank you

Comment: You have an extra parenthesis in each of your `substr()` calls.

Comment: @BoltClock: I think that's a typo, because this causes a parser error.

Comment: @Dennis Haarbrink: my thoughts exactly. But I'm a nitpick ;) (thanks Mark Byers for the edit)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should use the [identity](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) (===) operator to fix this :)

One of the main differences of === vs == is that === doesn't cast at all, it is a very strict comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Just write === instead of ==

you could also use something like:

```
if(preg_match("!([0-9]{2}).([0-9]{2}).([0-9]{2,4})!", $str, $found)){
    list($day, $month, $year) = array_shift($found);

    if(strlen($year)==4){
        //must be 4
    }else{
        //must be 2...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try === operator. The problem is that in both the cases the value returned is 0 and it is being compared with another 0.